# How can I transform some xml into a fixed length string using element attributes to define the value lengths

Tags: xml, xslt, attributes, xslt-1.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <Destination>acme.com</Destination>
    <Record>
       <FirstField length="10">AAAA</FirstField>
       <SecondField length="15">BBBB</SecondField>
       <SubRecord>
          <ThirdField length="20">CCCC</ThirdField>
          <FourthField length="8">DDDD</FourthField>
       </SubRecord>
    </Record>
</Root>
```

Hi, I have a requirement to take this xml example where the elements inside the  node will be dynamic & can be several layers deep, and create a fixed length string of text where each value is padded out to the left, using some xslt transformation that can process the xml until complete.   The length of each value is defined in the constant length attribute value   So the above example after transformation would be (inside the quotes so you can see the full length string:

```
"      AAAA           BBBB                CCCC    DDDD"
```

I've tried several attempts to create the required xslt to transform this, but haven't had much luck, as I don't know enough about xslt.

Is someone able to provide something that might work.   Needs to be in xsl 1.0.

Thanks.

Comment: I have rolled your question back. You were quite right to ask a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64326617/3016153) with your new requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<xsl:variable name="spaces" select="'                                   '"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
       <xsl:for-each select="//*[@length]">
           <xsl:variable name="spacelenght" select="@length - string-length(.)"/>
           <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($spaces, 1, $spacelenght), .)"/>
       </xsl:for-each>
       <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
   </xsl:template>
```

**Output**

```
"      AAAA           BBBB                CCCC    DDDD"
```

See transformation at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6q1S8AC

**For your updated question**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:variable name="spaces" select="'                                   '"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates/> 
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="node()" priority="-1">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="*[@Occurs]">
    <xsl:variable name="data">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:call-template name="copy">
        <xsl:with-param name="data" select="$data"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="seq" select="0"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="lastseq" select="number(@Occurs)"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="copy">
    <xsl:param name="data"/>
    <xsl:param name="seq"/>
    <xsl:param name="lastseq"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$data"></xsl:copy-of>
    <xsl:if test="$seq &lt; $lastseq">
        <xsl:call-template name="copy">
            <xsl:with-param name="data" select="$data"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="seq" select="$seq + 1"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="lastseq" select="$lastseq"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="*[@length]">
        <xsl:variable name="spacelenght" select="@length - string-length(.)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($spaces, 1, $spacelenght), .)"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
"      AAAA           BBBB                CCCC    DDDD                CCCC    DDDD                CCCC    DDDD                CCCC    DDDD                CCCC    DDDD                CCCC    DDDD                CCCC    DDDD                CCCC    DDDD                CCCC    DDDD                CCCC    DDDD"
```

See Transformation at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6q1S8AC/2

Comment: Yes, that worked, thanks so much for that.

Comment: Hi @Rupesh_Kr, I have a further requirement which I thought might of been simple to work out, but I can't.    I've edited the original problem above which shows where if it hits an Occurs, then it needs to loop around that node set x times, before continuing on.   Do you have an idea to solve this ?

Comment: @user3063486 See updated Answer

Comment: `<xsl:for-each select="1 to @Occurs">` requires XSLT 2.0.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, Sorry but it happens due to working simultaneously with my personal  work in same editor (Forget to change processor). :)
Answer Updated https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6q1S8AC/2

Comment: You should post this at OP's new question.