# How can I repeat a transformation of some xml using xslt

Tags: xml, loops, attributes, xslt-1.0, transform

Wanting to find out how I can take this xslt to the next level of being able to loop around a node x number of times, based on the occurs value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <Destination>acme.com</Destination>
    <Record>
       <FirstField length="10">AAAA</FirstField>
       <SecondField length="15">BBBB</SecondField>
       <SubRecord occurs="10">
          <ThirdField length="20">CCCC</ThirdField>
          <FourthField length="8">DDDD</FourthField>
       </SubRecord>
    </Record>
</Root>
```

The existing xslt looks like this

```
<xsl:variable name="spaces" select="'                                   '"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
       <xsl:for-each select="//*[@length]">
           <xsl:variable name="spacelength" select="@length - string-length(.)"/>
           <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($spaces, 1, $spacelength), .)"/>
       </xsl:for-each>
       <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
   </xsl:template>
```

And the desired output is like this.

```
"      AAAA           BBBB                CCCC    DDDD                CCCC    DDDD                CCCC    DDDD                CCCC    DDDD                CCCC    DDDD                CCCC    DDDD                CCCC    DDDD                CCCC    DDDD                CCCC    DDDD                CCCC    DDDD"
```

So as you can see, I am wanting to repeat the transform when it sees that its parent node contains an occurs value, ie so should loop around that particular node.    Element names are still dynamic so can't depend on a static name for this.    The only 2 things static are the attribute names of length & occurs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I transform some xml into a fixed length string using element attributes to define the value lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64274662/how-can-i-transform-some-xml-into-a-fixed-length-string-using-element-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

> The only 2 things static are the attribute names of length & occurs.

That's a strange situation. It is difficult to work with an input whose structure is is not entirely known. Still, you could do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:variable name="spaces" select="'                                                                        '"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//*[@length][not(ancestor::*/@occurs)] | //*[@occurs]"/>
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="//*[@length]">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($spaces, 1, @length - string-length(.)), .)"/>
</xsl:template> 
    
<xsl:template match="//*[@occurs]">
    <xsl:variable name="padded-strings">
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".//*[@length]"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:call-template name="repeat">
        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$padded-strings"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="times" select="@occurs"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="repeat">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>  
    <xsl:param name="times"/>
    <xsl:variable name="next" select="floor($times div 2)"/>
    <xsl:if test="$times mod 2">
        <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="$next">
        <xsl:call-template name="repeat">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="concat($string, $string)"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="times" select="$next"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Not quite right as the above does not create the (excluded the space padding and number of occurrences just for easier read) CCCC DDDD CCCC DDDD alternation, instead creates CCCC CCCC CCCC DDDD DDDD DDDD which is not what I need.

As mentioned, the full output needs to be "      AAAA           BBBB                CCCC    DDDD                CCCC    DDDD                CCCC    DDDD                CCCC    DDDD                CCCC    DDDD                CCCC    DDDD                CCCC    DDDD                CCCC    DDDD                CCCC    DDDD                CCCC    DDDD"

Comment: Well it's a lot of work to do when you're not sure what is known about the input and what can change. See if the edited answer fits.

Comment: Yes !, that looks to be exactly it, I tried some further layout variants on the xml and so far meets all the criteria for what I'm after.   Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As Already answer in your previous question

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:variable name="spaces" select="'                                   '"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()" priority="-1">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[@Occurs]">
        <xsl:variable name="data">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:call-template name="copy">
            <xsl:with-param name="data" select="$data"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="seq" select="0"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="lastseq" select="number(@Occurs)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="copy">
        <xsl:param name="data"/>
        <xsl:param name="seq"/>
        <xsl:param name="lastseq"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$data"/>
        <xsl:if test="$seq &lt; $lastseq">
            <xsl:call-template name="copy">
                <xsl:with-param name="data" select="$data"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="seq" select="$seq + 1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="lastseq" select="$lastseq"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[@length]">
        <xsl:variable name="spacelenght" select="@length - string-length(.)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($spaces, 1, $spacelenght), .)"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See Transformation at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6q1S8AC/4

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this.

```
 <xsl:variable name="spaces" select="'                                   '"/>
 
 <xsl:template match="*[boolean(@occurs)]">
    <xsl:param name="currentOccurs"/>

    <xsl:if test="$currentOccurs = '' or number($currentOccurs) &gt; 0">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
        <xsl:with-param name="currentOccurs">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$currentOccurs = ''">
              <xsl:value-of select="number(@occurs) - 1"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:value-of select="number($currentOccurs) - 1"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:with-param>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:if>  
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[boolean(@length)]">
    <xsl:variable name="spacelength" select="@length - string-length(.)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($spaces, 1, $spacelength), .)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:param name="currentOccurs"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*">
      <xsl:with-param name="currentOccurs" select="$currentOccurs"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
```